# WebView in Android not displaying a local HTML correctly

Tags: android, html, css, webview, google-glass

I have created a local HTML page that I want to display in **fullscreen** in my Android app.

What happens now is that the page opens correctly in a desktop browser, but **looks zoomed in** my Android device (Google Glass).

My **res/layout/webview.xml** is the standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></WebView>
```

My **HTML file** is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Cover</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="photo card">
        <img src="img/cover.png">
        <footer class="footer-cover">
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The *img/cover.png* is has the size of the Glass display: 640x360. Also, the app only needs to work in one device (Google Glass), so the **CSS** describes most sizes in pixels:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font: inherit;
}

div.card {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;

  position: absolute;

  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

div.card  a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00fcff;
}

footer {
  margin: 0 40px 28px 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;

  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

footer.footer-cover{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color:#00293F;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding:0 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no fillViewPort for WebView, you can try using

```
    getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

to load the content zoomed out.

Comment: Either of the following has no effect: webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

Comment: Try using `setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);` to have the content zoomed out all the way.

Comment: setDefaultZoom has been deprecated.